# How to Run YCSB for a redis Cluster on Ubuntu

Tags: redis, nosql, couchbase, ycsb

I am new to YCSB and i want to benchmark Redis using more than one cluster. I have tried with only one Redis on my localhost with the following command.

```
./bin/ycsb load redis -p redis.host=localhost -p redis.port=6379 -P workloads/workloada -p recordcount=200000 -s > d.dat
```

I am getting the currect ops/sec and other data.

Now i need to know how can run YCSB for more than one cluster.

Can anybody give an answer (steps to run this).

And it would be helpful if anyone can help to run Couchbase YCSB too.

Thanx..!!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps need to be done to perform YCSB bench marking with redis cluster

1) configure redis cluster with different nodes by referring to the document

http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

2) open the ycsb terminal,set up redis host ip address, port and specify the required parameters needed

```
 ./bin/ycsb load redis -p redis.host="ip address" -p redis.port="port" -P workloads/workloada -p recordcount=200000 -s > d.dat
```